# Duplicate record problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, query

```
create table #Personel
(
Ad varchar(100)
)

create table #Masa
(
MasaAdi varchar(100)
)

insert into #Personel values('deneme1')
insert into #Personel values('deneme2')
insert into #Personel values('deneme3')

insert into #Masa values('Masa1')
insert into #Masa values('masa2')
insert into #Masa values('masa3')

select Ad,MasaAdi from
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by MasaAdi order by ID,Ad ) as Sira,ID,Ad,MasaAdi
from (
select newid() as ID,Ad,MasaAdi 
from #Personel
cross join #Masa
)t
) t2 where Sira = 1 order by Ad
```

it's creating the result as shown below.

```
deneme1 - masa2
deneme2 - masa3
deneme1 - masa1
```

well,it's to be able to deploy to different tables two times the same personal.

```
e.g deneme1 - masa2
    deneme1 - masa1
```

I don't want to do that.I want to do something as shown below.

```
e.g deneme1-masa2
    deneme2-masa3
    deneme3-masa1
```

So,I don't want to deploy to different tables two times the same personal.

Comment: Why not deneme1-masa1, deneme2-masa2, deneme3-masa3. Please describe the expected output in a clear way. What if Personal and Masa contain different number of rows?

Comment: @bernd_k - As you mentioned,maybe.I just gave an sample output.

Comment: you want some unique random assignment?

Comment: bernd_k - yes, as you said

Comment: What do you want to do in cases where the number of rows in the two tables is not the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with 
cte1 as
(
    select *, row_number() over(order by Ad) RowNumber
    from #Personel
),
cte2 as
(
    select *, row_number() over(order by newid()) RowNumber
    from #Masa
)
select cte1.Ad, cte2.MasaAdi
from cte1
    join cte2 on
        cte1.RowNumber = cte2.RowNumber
```

Comment: @Cell-o - did the query work?

Comment: Do you really need both CTEs to be seeded with random ordering? I suspect only one is needed, and the other could just be ordered by a static column (this would be best if the column was clustered or an NC lead column). The extra sort may not be costly in small/trivial cases but I bet it would be easy to come up with cases where the impact is significant.